I got Error: read ECONNRESET Error on run dev nextjs 14.2.3
what is this error on nextjs run dev?
TypeError: fetch failed
at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async getVersionInfo (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js:215:21)
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
at async HotReloaderWebpack.start (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js:607:28)
at async startWatcher (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:156:5)
at async setupDevBundler (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:775:20)
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
at async initialize (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:78:30)
at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/shs/tmp/uniswap/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:249:36) {
[cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
errno: -104,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
}
}

in nextjs 14.3.2 development server startup i got this error which not related to each package I installed.
this is the project package.json.
package.json:
{
  "name": "uniswap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

node version: lts/iron (20.13.1)
I try to npm run dev and I get error

I also ran into the same problem just now.
deleting .next file and running npm run dev worked for me

its not any great issue mostly occurs when their is high load on your server and internet speed is slow. Mostly of time it automatically get resolve.for your reference i am attaching here link
Reconnect your internet

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
